# Generate sequence number without duplication

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to generate a unique sequence number based on some criteria for the first time and then store it in DB and each time i select this generated number incremented by one till reaching to threshold then resetting the generated number.

I have already generated the number and stored it in DB, there is a stored procedure that calls this number and increments it by one then updates the stored value with the new value(after incrementing). The problem now is that may be 2 users call the same procedure in the same time then each one will select the same stored generated number and then incrementing it and update stored value with new one(assume updating is done sequentially without dead locking) and in this case the 2 users get the same number and breaks the rule of number is unique how can i avoid concurrent users from selecting (getting) the same number?

**Note : The generated number is of type NVARCHAR(200)**

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the default valut of the primary key to NEWSEQUENTIALID() and the data type to UNIQUEIDENTIFIER.

Comment: The generated number its type is nvarchar(200) because it is formatted from some codes so unique identifier is not acceptable for me in this case

Comment: you can put the cursor at EOF then increment one with some critica if you are using HEXADECIMAL;

Comment: no i don't understand what do you mean!! assume i have a number in DB and its the seed for me and each time i select it i have to update the seed number by incrementing it with one the problem that i don't need the selected number to be used more than one time how can i avoid this duplication?

Answer (score -1):

A way you would be able to acheive this although it is a major hack and there has got to be a better way is to maintain another table with an auto incrementing key.

That key can then me inserted at the start of your procedure and the identity returned. You could then apply a modulus logic to return the unique incrementing key.

For example the table would be:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[uniqueidentifier](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [b] [bit] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

then each time you need the next key do the following where X is your recycle threshold:

```
declare @rtn int
delete * from uniqueidentifier 
insert into uniqueidentifier values (1)
set @rtn = scope_identity() % X
```

As I said it is messy and defo a hack but it would work however I stronly suggest that you may be able to restructure the logic of the stored procedure that creates this number

Hope this helps or there is a better suggestion

Comment: Again the generated number is formatted not generated in the first time after that its is incremented and its type is NVARCHAR(200) please read carefully my question before answering it!!!

Comment: Agreed that it is nvarchar and it is genertaed however there has got to be some pattern to how it is incremented whether this be character incrementation etc and for this you may be able to use an incrementing number as the basis of converting it to an alphanumeric string. It may be advisable to give an example of how the nvarchar string format looks and how it increments as people may be able to offer more advise based upon the structure of the required key. As for it being nvarchar there is a cast function